# How to use nova list on Ubuntu Cloud OpenStack

Tags: openstack, cloud

I just set up a new Ubuntu Cloud using Kilo-Release.
When I try to use "nova list" I need to source an openrc or stackrc file.
How do I access the commands in an multi-node setup using the openstack-installer?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the files

- .cloud-install/openstack-ubuntu-rc
- .cloud-install/openstack-admin-rc

Exactly what I was looking for.